# How to initialize a struct in c using posix_memalign

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, struct, initialization

I'm trying to figure out how to initialize a struct if I'm passed a memory location, the situation below is what I'm trying to do, but it throws "invalid initializer" shortened to relevant code

```
#ifndef PAGE_ALLOC_H
#define PAGE_ALLOC_H


typedef struct listNode
{
struct listNode *prev;
struct listNode *next; // prev/next element in linked list
char * address;
} listNode;
#endif

_____________________________________________

#include "page_alloc.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char ** args)
{
void * memptr;
int test = posix_memalign(&memptr, 2, 128); // test is > 1, values such as 16 and 22 is this ok? It does seem to return a valid memory address though, but can't test until struct lets me initialize to it...

listNode testNode = memptr; // this throws improper initialization flag, but how else do I do tell //the struct where the eligible memory is?? Isn't that what malloc does? Return a point to acquired //memory

// Now this is what I imagine doing after telling testNode where its allocated memory

testNode ->prev = somePreviousNode; // etc.

}
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong but what? I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I can't find any examples of posix_memalign nor can I find an explanation of properly initializing structs with a pointer to allocated memory. I need to dynamically add nodes because this is for a doubly linked list pointing to memory locations (used for keeping track of "pages")

Thanks for any insight!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testNode` is an object of the structure and you are assigning a pointer (`memptr`) to it:

```
listNode testNode = memptr;
```

Instead create a pointer to listnode and assign the allocated memory to it:

```
listNode *testNode = memptr;
```

**Note:** The value of the `alignment` parameter should satisfy two conditions:

1. should be a multiple of sizeof(void*)
2. should be a power of 2.

For eg,
if on your machine, `sizeof(void*) = 4`, then the acceptable value is `4,8,16...`.
if on your machine, `sizeof(void*) = 8`, then the acceptable value is `8,16,32..`.

Comment: Oh oops, thanks for that, is posix_memallign behaving properly? I'm not sure because I thought that it's supposed to return 1 on success not higher numbers like

Comment: No, `posix_memalign()` returns zero on success. Add that check to your code as well - `if(posix_memalign(&memptr, 2, 128) !=0) {//handle error};`

Comment: Do you by anychance know what I'm doing wrong with poxis_memalign?? There's jus so little examples of how to use it... -_-

Comment: OKay, i think the error is in your `alignment` parameter value. `alignment: the value must be a power of two multiple of sizeof (void *)`

Comment: Thank you for bearing through this with me, but one last question, do you have an idea why the alignment would have to be sizeof(void*)???? It seems a bit trivial, I figured it would have to be like 2, 4, 6, 8, etc..

Comment: Because of `memory alignment`, memory reads are done a word at a time (4 or 8 bytes). And since memory is byte addressable, addresses are usually accessed at factor of `4` or `8`. Hence the `void*`.